# HttpWebRequest error 401 on Pi3 with IoT Core c#

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-iot-core

I've used the search funktion before but the Solutions won't help in my case (don't know why). I've written a Code to call a IIS Webservice. The Code will run on my Desktop without any issues. On my Pi3 i will get an

```
(One or more errors occurred. (The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.)
```

error. What I'm doing wrong?
Thx Forward for helping me.

```
                Uri uri = new Uri(Url); //TempUrl is assigned a string beforehand
                request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

                // Add authentication to request   
                NetworkCredential c = new NetworkCredential("USER", "PASSWORD","DOMAIN");
                CredentialCache credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
                credentialCache.Add(uri, "NTLM", c);
                request.Credentials = c;

                Task<WebResponse> x = request.GetResponseAsync();
                x.Wait(20000);
                response = x.Result;
                // Get the response stream into a reader   
                reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: Do you have a valid reason why you are not awaiting the Task?

Comment: Not really, only lazyness. I will implement it in the next step.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I've Change the NetworCredentials as follows:

```
NetworkCredential c = new NetworkCredential(@"<Domain>\<USER>", "<PASSWORD>");
```

I don't know why, but it works.